# Tampermonkey script sometimes fails to start

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a tampermonkey script that sometimes works doesn't start.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Hitbox Emotes
// @namespace Hitbox Emotes
// @description The original Hitbox Emotes script with ober 13,000 emotes! - Request your custom emotes and mod badges here!
// @include *.hitbox.tv/*
// @include *.vgstreams.com/*
// @include *.multistream.xuzia.com/*
// @icon http://i.imgur.com/fa1Kkku.png
// @version 1.3.6
// ==/UserScript== 

function init()
{
    console.log("this is %o, event is %o, host is %s");

    var MainEmotes = document.createElement('script');
    MainEmotes.type = 'text/javascript';
    MainEmotes.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23313911/javascript/MainEmotes.js";

    var CustomStyle = document.createElement('link');
    CustomStyle.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    CustomStyle.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    CustomStyle.setAttribute('href', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23313911/css/CustomStyle.css')   

    var BackupEmotes = document.createElement('script');
    BackupEmotes.type = 'text/javascript';
    BackupEmotes.src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/GamingTom/11142192/raw/fdd206a1a9e892a0f0c55f1de253981d980fa0e8/MainEmotes.js";

    var CustomEmotes = document.createElement('script');
    CustomEmotes.type = 'text/javascript';
    CustomEmotes.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23313911/javascript/CustomEmotes.js";

    var CustomBadges = document.createElement('script');
    CustomBadges.type = 'text/javascript';
    CustomBadges.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23313911/javascript/CustomBadges.js";

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (head) {
        head.appendChild(MainEmotes);
        console.info("Hitbox Emotes: Main emotes loaded from " + MainEmotes.src)
        head.appendChild(BackupEmotes);
        console.info("Hitbox Emotes: Backup emotes loaded from " + BackupEmotes.src)
        head.appendChild(CustomEmotes);
        console.info("Hitbox Emotes: Custom emotes loaded from " + CustomEmotes.src)
        head.appendChild(CustomBadges);
        console.info("Hitbox Emotes: Custom badges loaded from " + CustomBadges.src)
        head.appendChild(CustomStyle);
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

I believe that is may have something to do with the

```
window.onload = init;
```

but if I just call the function, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: emotify is not defined" because the page sometimes doesn't fully load when it is called.

If anyone has any idea how to get the script to always start after the page has loaded, that would be great! If you need any more information, please ask. Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Tom

Comment: Use window.addEventListener instead

Comment: That didn't seem to work; what I need is for the script to start after the head is fully loaded but before the body. Hope this clears things up.